# How do I change directory in cmd from NSIS script?

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

My goal is to open a obs studio with virtual cam (--startvirtualcam) from cmd after installing my application and it will only opens from the directory where obs is installed.

So right now I am able to open a cmd but it's opening from my default system directory but I want to change directory where obs is installed and I am using nsExec plugin for this.

```
nsExec::ExecToStack 'cmd /k "$PROGRAMFILES64\obs-studio\bin\64bit\obs64.exe" --startvirtualcam'
```

This command is working but obs gives me error because I need to run it from same directory where OBS is installed

So I just want to know that how do I open cmd from nsis script and then change directory like cd 'path' and then run obs studio

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SetOutPath "$PROGRAMFILES64\obs-studio\bin\64bit"
nsExec::ExecToStack ...
...
```

or

```
nsExec::ExecToStack 'cmd /k cd /D "$PROGRAMFILES64\obs-studio\bin\64bit"&obs64.exe --startvirtualcam'
...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)